# How to grant user User Points after adding comment once?

Tags: drupal-7, comments, userpoints

I created a rule to grant users User Points when they added a comment on a node. However, I'd like to grant them these points only once. That means: they don't get more points when they react a second or a third time on the same node, but they will be granted points nevertheless after commenting on another node.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the Flags module: I created the flags called 'Commented on this node' & 'First reaction'* and rule called 'Commented on a node'. These are my rule's settings:

*EVENTS:* After saving a new comment

*CONDITIONS:*

- Content is of type Parameter: Content: `[comment:node]`, Content types:
  Article
- NOT Node is flagged Parameter: Flag: Commented on this node, node:
  `[comment:node]`, User on whose behalf to check: `[comment:author]`

*ACTIONS:*

- Grant points to a user Parameter: User: `[comment:author]`,
  Points: 2, Points category: Reaction, Entity: `[comment:node]`,
  Description: New reaction, Operation: Add,
  Display: false, Moderate: Automatically approved
- Flag a Node Parameter: Flag: Commented on a node, Node:
  `[comment:node]`, User on whose behalf to flag: `[comment:author]`, Skip
  permission check: false
- Flag a Comment: Parameter: Flag: First reaction, Comment: `[comment]`,
  User on whose behalf to flag: `[comment:author]`, Skip permission
  check: false

So, every time a user adds a comment to a certain node for the first time, the node is flagged as 'Commented on a node', the reaction is flagged as 'First reaction' and the user who added the comment is rewarded 2 points.

**I use the 'First comment' flag in a [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89853/how-to-deduct-user-points-after-deleting-comment-with-rules).*

Answer (score 0):

Rules must have:
Events: Before saving a comment

```
Conditions: this code

global $user;
$node  =array();
$query = db_select('comment', 'c');
$query->fields('c', array('nid'));
$query->condition('c.uid', $user->uid);
$result = $query->execute();
while ($res = $result->fetchAll()) {
foreach ($res AS $re) {
$node[] = $re->nid;
}
}

if(!in_array($comment->nid, $node)){
return TRUE;
}
```

Actions: grant users User Points

=============================

Conditions: Execute custom PHP code
or create custom Conditions

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_condition_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_rules_condition_info() {
  $conditions = array();
  $conditions['MYCONDITION'] = array(
    'label' => t('lable'),
    'parameter' => array(
      'user' => array(
        'type' => 'user',
        'label' => t('User'),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => t('Custom'),
    'callbacks' => array(
      'execute' => 'MYMODULE_rules_condition_MYCONDITION',
    ),
  );
  return $conditions;
}
function MYMODULE_rules_condition_MYCONDITION($user) {
$node  =array();
$query = db_select('comment', 'c');
$query->fields('c', array('nid'));
$query->condition('c.uid', $user->uid);
$result = $query->execute();
while ($res = $result->fetchAll()) {
foreach ($res AS $re) {
$node[] = $re->nid;
}
}

if(!in_array($comment->nid, $node)){
return TRUE;
}
}
```